# How to Delete tvOS table view rows

Tags: tableview, tvos

I have a table view set up on my tvOS application and i have add being able to get added by the user but i also want to be able to delete the data too.

Whats the method for editing and deleting a row in a tvOS table view?

any help will be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. It has two methods: `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`. Utilizing these within the view controller containing your `UITableView` will allow you to delete/edit rows.

Also, here is the corresponding Apple documentation regarding these methods and the rest of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html